# Unable to convert Json String to Json Object in c#

Tags: c#, json, console-application

I have an Json string which is `receiveCount({\"url\":\"http://www.google.com\",\"count\":75108})`

My complete Method is

```
public void GetPinCount(string url)
        {
            string QUrl = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url=" + url;
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest Request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(QUrl);
            Request.ContentType = "text/json";
            Request.Timeout = 10000;
            Request.Method = "GET";
            string content;
            using (WebResponse myResponse = Request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            };
           var json = JObject.Parse(content);
           var share_count = json["receiveCount"]["count"].ToString();
           Console.WriteLine("Share Count :" + share_count);
        }
```

When I am trying to access the count i am getting an exception like

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: r. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

Please tell me how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is not valid JSON :

```
receiveCount(`{\"url\":\"http://www.google.com\",\"count\":75108}`)
```

The valid JSON part is the parameter :

```
{"url":"http://www.google.com","count":75108}
```

You must extract the valid JSON part from your string to deserialize it.

Comment: I tried extracting it but still getting the same error

Comment: What did you extract ? What is the exact error ? If you extract the JSON string you cannot get an error saying that the string starts with the character 'r'.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong property.

You should use

```
var share_count = json["count"].ToString();
```

instead of,

```
var share_count = json["receiveCount"]["count"].ToString();
```

**Code to use with response:**

```
var json = JObject.Parse (content);
var share_url = json["url"];
Console.WriteLine ("Share URL:" + share_url);
var share_count = json["count"];
Console.WriteLine ("Share Count:" + share_count);
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
// Gets only the JSON string we need
content = content.Replace ("receiveCount(", "");
content = content.Remove (content.Length - 1);

// Converts JSON string to Object
var json = JObject.Parse (content);
var share_url = json["url"];
Console.WriteLine ("Share URL:" + share_url);
var share_count = json["count"];
Console.WriteLine ("Share Count:" + share_count);
```

Comment: first of all, i am unable to parse it to json.. then only i can think about getting data from it.

Comment: Seems the url (eg: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url=http://ticlotel.com/layered-medium-curly-hairstyles-2017.html) returns json string inside receiveCount method. So as a workaround I removed unwanted text from the response. Check if it works. :)

Comment: And FYI, there is no MIME type "text/json", "application/json" might be appropriate. (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)

Comment: It works when i removed receivedcount from the text and then i tried to parse the string to json